# Re-Render PrimeFaces elements after certain events

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to conditionally render my menuitem depending on which element I invoke my menu on.
Only problem is: The menuitem renders the moment the xhtml is loaded. Because of that, I'll only get "null" for my selected element. 
Of course I can catch that by saying "if it`s null, just render it", but the real problem is that, once rendered, the menuitem stays rendered.

Is there any way to render/re-render my menuitem right AFTER I open the menu(by then I'll have the information needed)?

I've tried several ways to aquire this:

- remoteCommand (I don't need to invoke any bean, so it seems to be the wrong tool)
- PageReload(Will obviously close my menue)
- Ajax(Might work, but I just started learning it -> In this case it did nothing)

EDIT:

Ajax does work. I've updated the code. Right now im re-rendering the contextMenue once I've selected an item, so the children will call their respective beans again and render correctly. 
Only flaw is:

- This takes for to long (guess this would lead to another question...)
- I don't want to re-render the menue, but the children! If I re-render the children directly, ajax can't find them by id anymore, so it will crash.

Any ideas?

test.xhtml

```
<p:contextMenu for="treeId" ajax="false" id="openSP">
    <p:menuitem value="Example" ajax="false"
        action="#{MyClass.method}" 
        rendered="#{MyClass2.renderItem}" >
    </p:menuitem>
</p:contextMenu>

<p:treeTable id="test" 
    ...
    <f:ajax event="select" render="openSP" /> 
    ...
</p:treeTable>
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what your actual problem is

Comment: I need to render my menue items asynchronely. But if I use ajax to achieve this, once my menue items become unrendered, render="openSP" can't find the item anymore since it uses javascripts "findElementById" internally. A possible solution is to render/unrender the parent(context menue). If I do this, it will just close, so I have to open it again which will result in an endless circle. So what I need is to re-render my menue items, asynchronely, whenever I open my context menue, without having the just described problems. I hope I could clarify my question, if not feel free to ask again.

Comment: Why not use CSS on it and 'hide' it instead of not rendering it?

Comment: I've tried using CSS  visibility:hidden; display:none; opacity:0; but unfortunately it seems like they all prevent the menu item from beeing found by ajax, after I've re-rendered it. So I guess my only option is to re-render a parent of the menu item.